# What is the stone space $S_n(T)$ for a theory with infinitely many equivalence classes, each class infinite?

Tags: general-topology, logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be the (first-order) language with one binary relation symbol $E$, and $T$ be the $L$-theory asserting that $E$ is an equivalence relation with infinitely many classes, each of which is infinite. Can you describe or otherwise characterize the stone spaces $S_n(T)$, for all $n$?

Comment: What is your question? What do you think? You did not even properly type in what the theory is...

Comment: @tomasz What exactly is the problem? I can't vote to re-open, but, as a model theorist, it's pretty clear to me what theory they're talking about and what they're asking.

Comment: @MikeHaskel: It is clear ot me, too. But it looks like OP didn't even bother to *read what he wrote*, not to mention *showing his work*. I don't think such questions deserve an answer, and certainly not one as careful as the one you have given (imho, a one-sentence hint would *maybe* be okay, if you are feeling generous) -- no offense to you, but I believe it is just detrimental to the site. If the question is improved by OP to fix this bad impression, I will gladly vote to reopen myself.

Comment: @MikeHaskel: Also, I don't think you should put too much work into improving the question for OP, either. I'm not saying this is never a good idea, but not in this case: the question is not particularly interesting, and it does seem like rewarding OP for his laziness.

Answer (score 5):

First, of course, note that the theory is complete and has quantifier elimination (in the language with one binary relation symbol for the equivalence). The entire analysis to follow essentially uses quantifier elimination to say that a type that completely describes equality and equivalence among its variables is a complete type.

To start, see that there is only one 1-type in $S_1(T)$, since there are no interesting unary relations.

Next, consider 2-types. A 2-type $p(x,y)$ gets to say whether $x$ and $y$ are equal, and whether they are equivalent. There are three possibilities: equal (and therefore equivalent), not equal but still equivalent, and not equivalent (and therefore not equal). Therefore, $S_2(T)$ consists of just these three points.

For higher $n$, a type specifies equality and equivalence for each pair of variables. There are, however, some dependencies between the different choices: for example, if $x$ is equivalent (or equal!) to $y$ and $y$ is equivalent to $z$, $x$ must be equivalent to $z$. Therefore $S_n(T)$ will consist of all the consistent ways of making these choices for all pairs of variables, so $S_n(T)$ is finite. Exactly how many points it contains is a not too difficult (but not too enlightening) combinatorics problem.

Comment: Note that this was an explicit analysis, since the OP asked what the stone spaces *were*. If you just want to see that they're finite, use a back-and-forth argument to see that $T$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical. In any $\aleph_0$-categorical theory, each $S_n(T)$ is finite.